# Pushing div over <a> class

Tags: html, css, menu, navbar, nav

I need this in order to apply a shadow to menu buttons.
I know z-index should do the trick, but I can't make it to work!

http://jsfiddle.net/blackice856/TR4Ls/5/

```
    <div id="nav">
<ul>
<div id="navshadow"><li><a>TEST</a></li></div>
<div id="navshadow"><li><a>TEST</a></li></div>
<div id="navshadow"><li><a>TEST</a></li></div>
<div id="navshadow"><li><a>TEST</a></li></div>
<div id="navshadow"><li><a>TEST</a></li></div>
<div id="navshadow"><li><a>TEST</a></li></div>
</ul>
</div>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: First at all that's invalid HTMl you can't nest direct divs inside the ul only li .... and ID must be unique.... And if you want a shadow use just box-shadow property

Comment: The only permitted child element of an `<ul>` is a `<li>`. What exactly are you aiming for?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do, but like @Danko says you cannot have `div` elements as direct descendants of `ul` - the only valid descendant node of a `ul` or `ol` is an `li`.  And he is also correct that you should use `class="navshadow"` not `id` as IDs must be unique.  But really you haven't provided enough information about your intended result to help past that... why not just add `box-shadow` to your `a` elements?

Comment: Oh yeah right, that is a class, I wrote that wrong and I completly forgot that ul's can only nest the li class. I already tried the box-shadow property, but Im looking for a shadow on both sides of the button (left and right), and this is what I get http://jsfiddle.net/blackice856/TR4Ls/13/.
Btw, isn't box-shadow a bit different among browsers? I mean, I didn't want a lot of compatibility problems. I used to do shadows with images, is that a good choice?

Answer (score 1):

Hi then first at all just remove that divs, you can have only direct `li` tags inside `ul` elements, also you don't need that :

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
   <li><a>TEST</a></li>
   <li><a>TEST</a></li>
   <li><a>TEST</a></li>
   <li><a>TEST</a></li>
   <li><a>TEST</a></li>
   <li><a>TEST</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then just use `box-shadow` as the property either in the `li` or `a` tags:

```
#nav li{
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

<sub>[Follow this link to learn the syntax](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/)</sub>

On `:hover` you can change the `z-index` value but remember to set a non-static position on the element:

```
#nav li:hover{
  position:relative;
  z-index:10;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TR4Ls/11/)**

Answer (score 0):

try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppollono/TR4Ls/14/)

```
#nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 960px;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
}
#nav a {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    height:60px;
    line-height:60px;
    width:160px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #969696;
    font-family:'opensanslight';
    font-size:14px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #e35805;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
}
#nav a:hover {
    color: #fa650c;
    border-bottom:5px solid #fa7d31;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);      
}
.navshadow {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:160px;
    height:60px;
    background-color:#000000;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2000;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, im looking for both left and right sides of the button with a shadow, is that possible?